# SQL Query - Convert certail column into row

Tags: sql

I have a four rows of SQL Request, and it ll be two colunm should be Row (karatage and Unit weight) and remaing ll be the value of the column (Location  and quantity),

Ex: Output Result
[image]

Required Output like,

[image]

Comment: Strange, the expected result includes location codes HNR, TCR etc. not found in the sample data.

Comment: Yes many location code is there, i have mentioned only one location code in sample date.

Comment: in MS SQL Server, you can do that with pivot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kenobonn/pivot-on-two-or-more-fields-in-sql-server

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, have matching sample data and expected result. I.e. a [mcve]. Also add a tag for for the dbms you're using.